# Parallel Building in Recursive Autotools Project

Tags: makefile, autotools

I have a large project which uses a recursive autotools structure.  Most of the build time is spent on a single directory within this, so I want to make that directory build in parallel.  I've found documentation related to make's `-j` option to enable parallel building, but the question is, where should I specify `-j` in my `Makefile.am` for the directory I am building?

I understand that it's better to use a non-recursive structure for parallel building, but that's too big a job for now, and I'm hoping there's still a way to make this one directory build in parallel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not your task as a maintainer to specify the level of parallelism of the build, because it depends on the machine you are building on. Often passing the number of CPUs to `-j` is a good idea, but not always. What is supposed to happen is that a user just runs `make` with the appropriate `-j` flag. If you also happen to be that user and you are tired of passing `-j` explicitly all the time, then

```
export MAKEFLAGS=-j2
```

from your shell profile (e.g. `.bashrc`) and have `make` always consider this option.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a linux distribution, and further assuming you would like the builds to be adaptive, you might try:

```
export MAKEFLAGS=-j`nproc`
```